# Android: выбор файла

Tags: android, java

Нужно реализовать такую фишку: приложение просит выбрать в файлах изображение,с помощью установленных программ (например "Мои файлы"),чтобы потом из файла вытащить его полный путь. Такое я видел...Ну в будильнике, приложении ВК и т.д.

Как это реализовать?

Сначала я хотел просто получить список файлов в ListView с помощью класса File,но понял,что это будет не удобно для пользователя. Должна быть альтернатива как в других программах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Допустим вы хотите получить картинку из галереи.

Тогда пишем следующее:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

Это запустит галерею. При выборе фото сработает метод **onActivityResult()**, поэтому переопределяем его:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode)
    {
         case 1:
         {
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
             {
                 Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
             }
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

В объекте **chosenImageUri** есть путь к объекту галереи, выглядит вот так примерно: **media/xcvbcxvb/sdfadf/xvb/12332**

Чтобы из этого бреда получить путь к СД карте пишем:

```
final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( chosenImageUri, null, null, null, null );
cursor.moveToFirst();
final String filePath = cursor.getString(0);
cursor.close();
```

Вуаля, в объекте **filePath** лежит нужный нам полный путь к файлу

Comment: У меня так и не получилось получить полный путь к файлу с помощью вашего кода

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как выбирать другие файлы. Например из папки загрузки и др.

Answer (score 2):

получить ссылку можно так

```
chosenImageUri.getEncodedPath()
```

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, new String[] {
  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0); // Link to the image
```